# SiebelDataBean - Logon Request XXX on connection XXXXXXX was abandoned

Tags: api, siebel

We are using SiebelDataBean to connect to Siebel EAIObjMgrAPI component using below process provided.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/OIRef/Customizing_Siebel_Object_Interfaces12.html

The application works fine for a while and then start throwing below error, kindly let me know if anyone else has encountered this issue.

[CMGR WARNING] Received notification: The task 257950792 has either been shutdown or timed-out connection:f600448
Logon Request 106 on connection 2100445 was abandoned after 30001 ms because it timed out.(SBL-JCA-00317)

Answer (score 0):

Check the SISNAPI idle timeout setting on the EAI component parameters. If there is no activity for that much seconds, the system logs out the session to preserve memory.

Comment: SISNAPI Connection Maximum Idle Time (ConnIdleTime)  = -1 (-1 means Infinity – means no timeout for idle session)

Comment: How you can set this connLdle = -1? can someone please help.